# How to add a file extension using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have "image1.png" and I want to save the extension ".png" in a variable so I can add the file extension dinamically in the "image src" tag

I know how to do this with PHP:

```
<body>
<?php $variable = "png"; ?>

<img src="image1.<?php echo $variable ?>">  

</body>
```

Is there any way to do this same thing but with javascript??

I have been trying "Element.innerhtml" and "document.write" with no luck so far.

Thank you

Comment: Of course you can set attribute/property values in javascript using variables. This one in particular accepts a string, so you can do string concatenation.

Comment: set the image's src?

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite know why you want to achieve this, but the below does what you'd expect.

Edit: As per your comment I've updated this to only append an extension, instead of rebuilding the full src URL, and to do this for all images on the page. You could add logic to see if an extension already exists, and exclude those.

```js
var imgExt = 'ico';
var imageArray = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
    imageArray[i].src = imageArray[i].src + '.' + imgExt;
}
```

```html
<!-- Note that the src attribute is missing an extension. -->
<img id='A' src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon' >
<img id='B' src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon' >
<img id='C' src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon' >
```

The output HTML is as follows: 
`<img id="someImage" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jacob.
The reason I want to achieve this is because I want to load either png or svg images depending on browser's version.
If the browser is compatible with svg, then the "variable" will obtain the value ".svg", if not ".png". 

This is a method that works perfectly for me in PHP and I am looking a way to make it work in JS.

Your solution works fine, however I would have to create a variable for each image.

Do you know a way to include this JS variable inside the image src tag and only to replace file extension?

Comment: @user289877 Makes sense - I've updated my answer to append the extension to the existing src URL.

Comment: @user289877 I've updated again to apply this change to all images on the page.